# Jquery: how to get the selected option from a select element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I apologize if this has been answered here before, but I've searched and I'm not finding what I need. I'm creating a select box and populating the options with the name of a congressional bill and the option id with the bill number. Once the bill is selected, I need to fire off an even that will pass the id to a function. I can't figure out how to do that last part. I can add .click to the select element, but that takes the id of the first option, not the option that was picked. I can't get .click to work on the option itself. I've also tried using .focus and .select on the option element, but they aren't working either. How can I get jquery to recognize the option I've chosen? Any suggestions?

```
$.each(response.objects, function(){
            billNum = response.objects[count].id;
            $('#billSelector').append('<option id=\''+billNum + '\'>'     +response.objects[count].title + '</option>');
            count++;
        });//each
        $('option').focus(function(){
            alert($('option').attr('id'));
        });//function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can listen for change event on `select`

```
$('#billSelector').on('change',function(){
  // get id of selected option
  var id = $('option:selected',this).prop('id');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
$("#billSelector").change(function(){
   var selectedOptionId = $("#billSelector option:selected").attr("id");
   alert("you have selected option: " + selectedOptionId);
});
```